# How to animate specific item of Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is a Image of Recycler Item:
[image]

I want when i click on plus button new item added with animation
Here is a code

```
viewHolder.cart_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            menu.add(position+1,menu.get(position));
            Singleton.getInstance().getMenuExtraArrayList().add(position+1,menu.get(position));
            ((CartActivity)context).cartIconCounter.setText( Singleton.getInstance().getMenuExtraArrayList().size()+"");
            ((CartActivity)context).setPrice();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            setAnimation(position,viewHolder.itemView);

        }
    });
```

and here is setAnimationMethod

```
private void setAnimation(int psition, View itemView) {
    if (psition > lastPosition)
    {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        itemView.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = psition;
    }
}
```

and initially value of lastposition is -1

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing here by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` is telling the recycler view that **all** of your dataset has been changed and they should be redrawn, while you actually need just the added view at `position+1` to be inserted.

To only notify the recycler view about the inserted item you can just call `notifyItemInserted(position+1)` (assuming that the list item index and the recycler view item position are identical)

You might also be interested to learn a neat way to implement RecyclerView animations [here](https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213), which uses the built-in `android:layoutAnimation` attribute to define your layout insertion animations, i.e.:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"                                        
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_fall_down"
    />
```